Matplotlib InlineBackend error on Jupyter Lab (NameError: name '_fetch_figure_metadata' is not defined)
So I got this code from a Image Processing course which opens/displays an image using matplotlib.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%config InlineBackend.figure_formats = 'retina'

img = plt.imread('komodo.jpg')
plt.axis("off")
plt.imshow(img)

When I run the cell for the first time, I get this lenghty error
The error is too long, I've added the starting and the end part.
When I run it for the second time and so on, this is what I get
Jupyter Lab Version = 4.0.11
The complete story -

I ran the code and it worked, then I saw a notification that said that there is a new Jupyter lab version available.
I updated it using this command conda update -c conda-forge jupyterlab.
And since then the code is not working.
I changed the and launched jupyter lab with the older version but it did not work.
I tried adding %matplotlib inline to the cell. No luck.
And there isn't anything about this error on the Internet! NameError: name '_fetch_figure_metadata' is not defined.


The middle error you show as a screenshot (which is frowned upon and needs to be fixed) has a big clue to a recent bug that has come up. Note that although retina in your code is spelled correctly, the letters are jumbled in the end of the error where it says not matching a supported format. Let me dig up the link about this.

It reminds me of this, this and this. That last one leads to here, which I think gets to the root of the issue. Have you taken the code and cleaned it somewhere of line endings or any quotes or anything?

Hmmm...this is the issue but that says markdown cells. Yours is a code cell. {There's this related issue that is about making files](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/14715). DId you make that code in some other way?

By the way this is the screenshot showing retina being scrambled. Can you try adjusting the line endings using a coding text editor that isn't Jupyter and/or use a different browser?

That error about plt.axis("off") hints about deprecation in the first screenshot but someone wrote in 2022 they were using it. Maybe no longer the way? There's other options listed there, do they work for you alternatively?

Plus your code all runs fine if you go here and click on 'launch binder'. Download a komodo.jpg file from Wikipedia to your machine and then upload it into the session using the 'Upload' button along the top right side, near the 'New' button. Then open a new notebook using the button in the upper right and paste in your code and run it, first fixing the file name if it doesn't match. It will work there. Then try here with JupyterLab 4.1. It works as well,

 You'll need to first run %pip install matplotlib in a cell there and then when it completes the install successfully restart the kernel before running the code though because matplotlib doesn't come installed in that JupyterLab session. But you should see it work there, too.

Thanks guys! I tried some of the things you suggested, but unfortunately, none of them worked. But I reinstalled anaconda from scratch and it's working fine now. The issue was with one of the anaconda lib files getting changed during updation. Thanks anyways!

The following solution worked for me in VS Code.
Uninstall and reinstall matplotlib, then change the depreciated %config line as follows:
from matplotlib_inline.backend_inline import set_matplotlib_formats

set_matplotlib_formats('retina')


IMO it might be helpful if you specify the versions of the key software used (jupyter, matplotlib, vscode, operating system, etc).

matplotlib: 3.9.0
